# Declare each shuffles string array elements

Tags: javascript, php, html, shuffle

What I want is to create a label or declare it as something for the each shuffles string array elements, so that i will be able to apply each shuffles string array elements to drop and drop.
. So there are three string array elements. After applying the shuffle function form the code below, it will show like

```
 <script>
 //Parses the variable from php to this Javascript part
 var js_var = "<?php echo $output ?>";

 //document.write(js_var);

 //Splits the string when the delimiter # is detected
  var split_str= js_var.split("#");
 //var js_var = "Try123";
 //displays original string
  document.writeln(js_var+"<br >"+"<br >");


 //sent to shuffle(o) function to scramble the elements
  var shuffle_str = shuffle(split_str);

 //displays each of the shuffled string array elements
  for (i=0;i<shuffle_str.length;i++)
{
 document.write(shuffle_str[i] + "<br >");
}

 //document.writeln(js_var);

 function shuffle(o){ //v1.0
  for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j]  
   = x);
  return o;
};


</script>

<button id="showcontent" onclick="window.location.reload()">Scramble</button>

</body>
```

Comment: Break your problem down into two parts.  First, create the shuffle function, and then do the javascript work.  If you are having trouble with one or the other parts, ask another question about that particular part.  This question as it is is too vague.

Comment: ps- Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

I would do that with something like [jQuery UI Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable) like this

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BGDEe/

HTML:

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">Jane likes</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">to</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">read book</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
 #sortable {
     list-style-type: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
 }
 #sortable li {
     margin: 3px 3px 3px 0;
     padding: 1px;
     float: left;
     font-size: 12px;
     text-align: center;
     cursor: pointer;
     border-color: transparent;
     background: none;
 }
 #sortable li.ui-state-highlight {
    height: 15px;
    width: 20px;
 }
 #sortable:hover li {
     border-color: #d3d3d3;
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
 }
```

JS:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    cursor: 'move',
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    update: function () {}
});
$("#sortable").disableSelection();
```

This will handle drag and drop pretty well, you just add code inside that `update: function () {}` if you want to handle drag and drop result.

Everything that is left for you, is to generate appropriate HTML where each word is in separate `<li>` element for drag and drop to happen and use class like `class="shuffle-word"`, instead of my current `id="sortable"`, and change jQuery selector appropriately.

Because your question and example is very hard to understand, I will leave my example as it is in hope, that you will be able to solve it by yourself.

I will just add that the part where you generate HTML is this one

```
//displays each of the shuffled string array elements
document.write('<ul class="shuffle-word">');
for (i=0; i < shuffle_str.length; i++) {
    document.write('<li class="ui-state-default">'+shuffle_str[i]+'</li>');
}
document.write('</ul>');
```

Afterwards you initialize it properly (but remember to put everything inside document ready event callaback)

```
$(".shuffle-word").sortable({
    cursor: 'move',
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    update: function () {}
});
$(".shuffle-word").disableSelection();
```

And style it as you please. Just note that my solution requires jQuery, jQuery UI and jQuery UI CSS (optional, if you add more css by yourself).

Comment: For example, for this part, yours is hardcore. what if mine is get the sentence from the database? Because as what I'm doing now is using a symbol "#" to make the sentence split. Which the sentence is get from the database.                                            <ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">Jane likes</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">to</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">read book</li>
</ul>

Comment: Read my answer to the end, I have modified your `displays each of the shuffled string array elements` part of code, so my drag-n-drop solution is no longer "hard-coded".

Comment: May i know where am i suppose to put this? in php? or just below the  
//displays each of the shuffled string array elements ?                           $(".shuffle-word").sortable({
    cursor: 'move',
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    update: function () {}
});
$(".shuffle-word").disableSelection();

Comment: I have edit the question. Can help me take a look? I dont get what should i add on and change. @Deele

Comment: @user3773928 Before you can use my code, you need to learn basic concepts of jQuery which is JavaScript library tad gives many functions that gives you shorthand access to JavaScript functionality. Your original question is complex task, that you should try to achieve by yourself, if you have questions during that process, then go ahead, but we are not here to do all of work for you.